# Regex - links not to allow double question mark Java

Tags: java, regex

I have the below deep links and Regex should fail if the string has 2 or more questions marks and ideally should contain always one question mark

Here is the Regex I am using :   `"^(?!.*[?][?].*)+$"`

```
TestMe?src=SRCH&reset=true - regex should pass
TestMe?src=SRCH?reset=true - regex should fail
```

Comment: Your regex `^(?!.*[?][?].*)+$` only matches empty strings and fails all other strings. You need `s.matches("(?s)^(?!(?:[^?]*[?]){2}).*")` or use the solution below.

Comment: You decided to solve this problem with regular expressions. Now you have two problems.

Comment: The above regex works

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for 2 adjacent ?s:

```
"^(?!.[?][?].)+$"
       ^  ^
```

Your "fail" string doesn't have that:

```
TestMe?src=SRCH?reset=true
      ^--------^
```

You don't need to use regex to check for two question marks:

```
boolean containsTwoQuestionMarks(String str) {
  return str.indexOf('?') != str.lastIndexOf('?');
}
```

Comment: I am not looking for adjacent ?s, overall 2 or more ? should fail. Need Regex as I would like to append to existing Regex

Comment: Slightly more efficient: `int first = str.indexOf('?'); return first >= 0 && index < str.lastIndexOf('?');`